# How to make Arduino communicate with MySQL?

Tags: programming, arduino-yun

I am trying to send data from my Arduino to my database but it seems that the process is not successfully beginning. Here is my code for Arduino:

```
#include <Process.h>
#include <Bridge.h>
int temperature;
void setup() {
  Bridge.begin();  // Initialize Bridge
}
void loop() {
  int temperature = random(0, 100);
  Process p;               
  p.begin("143.248.181.36/db.php");// 143.248.181.36 address of localhost.
  p.addParameter(String(temperature));
  p.run();
  delay(5000);
}
```

I am using xampp and I put db.php inside the htcocs folder. Can anyone point out why it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with those libraries, but a quick look gives me the impression that Bridge and Process are used together to make system calls over serial connection on the host system. Based on that..

First, looking at [Arduino Process Tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Process) Process.begin() should call the process that you want to call. Maybe something like this:

```
p.begin("curl"); // Assuming you have curl installed on your host system
p.addParameter("http://143.248.181.36/db.php?temperature=SOMEVALUE");
```

Second, your PHP script is broken.

```
/ check connection
```

^ That comment is missing a second slash /

You should definitely get the PHP/MySQL part working standalone before attempting to integrate Arduino in the process. I'm a bit doubtful that $argv gets populated unless you're running the script from command line. If you're making a GET HTTP request (as you would with curl) you might wanna try instead

```
$temperature = $_GET['temperature'];
```

If the above works as a workaround, you should get an entry into your MySQL table if you visit the URL below with your browser.

```
"http://143.248.181.36/db.php?temperature=100"
```

In any case, get the PHP script working first in your browser. One step at a time.